# Why does this "paging" query throw a "does not match with a table name or alias" error?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pagination

Warning, "ugly" query alert (MS SQL Server 2008):

```
SELECT BaseDocs.* FROM (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY BaseDocs.DateUpdated DESC) AS Row, BaseDocs.* 
    FROM BaseDocs INNER JOIN DocCats ON BaseDocs.DocId = DocCats.DocId  
    WHERE DocCats.CatId IN (4) AND BaseDocs.BaseId = 1
  ) AS Paged 
  WHERE Row > 0 AND Row <=3
```

This query throws this error:

> The column prefix 'BaseDocs' does not match with a table name or alias
>   name used in the query.

This query is against these tables:

```
BaseDocs Table
 - DocId PK
 - BaseId FK
 - ...

DocCategories Table
 - CatId PK
 - ...

DocCats (join) Table
 - DocId FK PK 
 - CatId FK PK
```

After "hacking" at this query for so long, I think my brain is frying... but it's close, I can feel it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: argh excellent point... duh, sorry... got distracted while writing the question. ;) Editing now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just don't specify a table alias in your `SELECT` - that table alias is visible only **inside** your subquery!

```
SELECT *
FROM 
   (SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY BaseDocs.DateUpdated DESC) AS Row, 
        BaseDocs.* 
    FROM BaseDocs 
    INNER JOIN DocCats ON BaseDocs.DocId = DocCats.DocId  
    WHERE 
         DocCats.CatId IN (4) 
         AND BaseDocs.BaseId = 1
  ) AS Paged 
WHERE 
   Row > 0 AND Row <= 3
```

or alternatively: use the alias given to your subquery:

```
SELECT Paged.* .....
```

Comment: OMG, such a small change... Thanks for the help, really appreciate it!